# Making a flat list out of a multi-type nested list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

I have the following list --

```
[1,[2,3],4,[5,[6,7]]]
```

And I need to make it flat --

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

To do this, I am currently using a `for` loop with `isinstance`, with the number of loops being `#nests - 1`.

What woud be the simplest way to make the nested list flat? Thank you.

A similar question which deals with making a flat list out of nested lists (only) can be found here: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hauled from [webhelpers.misc.flatten](http://sluggo.scrapping.cc/python/WebHelpers/modules/misc.html?highlight=flatten#webhelpers.misc.flatten)

```
def flatten(iterable):
    """Recursively iterate lists and tuples.
    """
    for elm in iterable:
        if isinstance(elm, (list, tuple)):
            for relm in flatten(elm):
                yield relm
        else:
            yield elm
```

**EDIT:** The iterable test here is quite naive and can be improved by checking for the presence of `__iter__` or an instance of the `collections.Iterable` abstract base class.

**EDIT 2:** @ChristopheD is absolutely correct, this is a dupe so head over to the linked question.

Comment: Hi, I have hard times in understanding this line "for relm in flatten(elm)". How recursive is working here., After every iteration is it going to "yield relm" line? ? Can someone explain me using dry run? Please

Comment: We can handle iterable like this............ try:
#         it_is = iter(x)
#     # If it's not iterable return the list as is
#     except TypeError:
#         yield x

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def flat(mlist):
    result = []
    for i in mlist:
        if type(i) is list:
            result.extend(flat(i))
        else:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```