# Flattening list of list using other technique

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand this code for flattening list:

```
def flatten(iterable):
    """Recursively iterate lists and tuples.
    """
    for elm in iterable:
        if isinstance(elm, (list, tuple)):
            for relm in flatten(elm):
                yield relm
        else:
            yield elm here
```

Source: [Making a flat list out of a multi-type nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499839/making-a-flat-list-out-of-a-multi-type-nested-list)

However I am not able to understand recursive statement and how control is flowing. Specially these two lines:

```
   for relm in flatten(elm):
            yield relm
```

Can I get gist of how recursive is working at every iteration, that would be a great help.

And Can we use some other approch to do this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Iterate protocol

In python there is such a key concept as iteration protocol. Iteration protocol is used every time you:

- Use a for loop
- Unpack/pack a tuple
- Use list comprehension
- Yield any value

Basically iteration protocol is used every time you want to process some sequence of data. Let's use list creation as example. Whenever you call:

```
my_list=list(x)
```

Python interpreter is calling [__next__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method on x and then adding result to end of result list (which is empty at the beginning). And it stops when next(x) throws [StopIteration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration).

## So what with this yields?

[Yield](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) is pretty similar to return but it does not terminate the function. Result of the function with yields inside is [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator). Generators implements [__next__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) method and they can be used in iterate protocol.
Let's look at this function:

```
def gen():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
```

This function will be generator and it will behave like this:

```
>>>gen()
<generator object a at 0x0000000002A1EAF0>
>>>list(gen())
[1,2,3]
>>>i=gen()
>>>next(i)
1
>>>next(i)
2
>>>next(i)
3
>>>next(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

So every time you call next(i) python only execute code till next [yield](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) and returns it's value.
If you want to learn more about it I recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2PkkMS2Ack) lecture or answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301253/what-exactly-is-pythons-iterator-protocol) question.

## P.S

Instead of this lines:

```
for relm in flatten(elm):
            yield relm
```

you can use:

```
yield from flatten(elm)
```

Answer (score 1):

(I deleted my comment and posted is as answer, because my edit was too long.)

The flow control is as follows:

- `iterable` is the nested list you have at the beginning,
- the `for` and later `if` differentiates if the `elm` (element from `iterable`) is a `list` or `tuple` type,
- if yes, then the statement under `if` makes the recurrence happen and the `elm` becomes new `iterable`,

...this happens for every element inside the main list until the `elm` isn't `list` or `tuple`

- the function returns `generator` object, so to get to all outputs you have to call a `list` on it.

What you also can do, is adding `print` statements to see what is happening; for example:

```
def flatten(iterable):
    for elm in iterable:
        if isinstance(elm, (list, tuple)):
            print(elm)
            for relm in flatten(elm):
                yield relm
        else:
            print(elm)
            yield elm
```

If we input `a = [1, 2, 3,[[4, 5], 5, (1, 2, 3)], 2]` and say `list(flatten(a))` we get:

```
1
2
3
[[4, 5], 5, (1, 2, 3)]
[4, 5]
4
5
5
(1, 2, 3)
1
2
3
2
```

This way we can see, what the function was working on in every step.

Comment: In your example when flatten() is called on elm=[4, 5] then iterable is replaced by elm... Then how flatten() keeps track of [5, (1, 2, 3)] rest elements. In this line: for relm in flatten(elm):

Comment: It keeps track of rest of the elements because of `for elm in iterable:`. The recursion happens for current element, until it is exhausted. Then the `for` continues.I think you can try to modify it further to see when the recursion is "inside" a nested list adding more `print` statements.

Comment: Can you show it in a flow diagram. I am sorry if it's too much to ask but this will help me to understand better.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Q5GOO
It's not the best, especially the second if, but maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Wonderful Solution!!